# ¿Cómo agregar referencia de servicio en Xamarin.forms?

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo que agregar una referencia de un Web Service en mi proyecto de Xamarin.forms y no me aparece la opción de "Agregar referencia de servicio".

Por lo que tengo entendido debo eliminar las opciones para que la App funcione en Windows 8 y 8.1, pero cuando quiero sacar las opciones estas no me aparecen.

¿Cómo debería hacer?

Estas son las opciones que me aparecen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de tanto investigar encontré la solución en otro post de StackOverflow en inglés:

Una opción es cambiar manualmente el TargetFrameworkProfile de .net en el archivo .csproj, para esto hacer lo siguiente:

1- En Visual Studio descargar el proyecto PLC.

2- Editar el archivo .csproj (Botón derecho en el proyecto descargado o podemos ir a la misma ruta donde se encuentra el archivo y editarlo con el notepad)

3- Encontrar el tag `<TargetFrameworkProfile></TargetFrameworkProfile>`

4- Dentro del tag, cambiar el valor a Profile7. Guardar el archivo y cerrarlo.

Después recargar el proyecto en Visual Studio y ahí vamos a poder agregar la referencia ;)

Dejo aquí el link de la solución para el que le interese!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486153/xamarin-forms-remove-winphone-target-platform-on-visual-studio/45486300#45486300?newreg=d3e1b8cd687242e6ab9b2627b91b1e6d